# Creating components in change detection hook

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, components

My current component has the responsibility of performing two tasks, in chronological order:

1. `ngOnInit`: Loop through data that was queried from a server, and insert a component for each part of the list.
2. `ngAfterViewInit`: Subscribe to a `@ViewChildren(MyDirective)` `changes` `observable` and, on change, insert components dynamically.

The error I get is the following:

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '0'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?`

It does seem to make sense, as *I am creating* components in a change detection hook.

My current code, simplified to a minimum example that throws the same error as my own:

Directive

```
@Directive({selector: '[min-insert]'})
export class MinDirective {
    @Input("min-insert") public minData;
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Component (The important part here is not the exact code, but that a component gets created on subscription change.)

```
...
someData : any;
@ViewChildren(MinDirective)d:QueryList<MinDirective>;
ngOnInit(){
    this.service.doHTTPStuff(...); //Assigns real data to "someData"
}
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.d.changes.subscribe(()=> {this.d.forEach(dir=>{
        let cF = this.componentService.getComponentFactory(...);
        dir.viewContainerRef.clear();
 (<IC>dir.viewContainerRef.createComponent(cF).instance).setData(dir.minData);

    })});
}
```

And here's the template, which has the "interesting" part for this error, I guess:

```
<div *ngFor="let minData of someData">
    <ng-template [min-insert]="minData"></ng-template>
</div>
```

Basically, the first thing that should happen, is that `someData` gets looped through, and for each `minData` in it, an empty shell for my directive gets created. Once I'm thus successfully able to fetch the directives with `@ViewChildren`, I want to "replace" them by creating a component on them.

If I remove the for-loop and only make one "empty shell" in a manner that I do not need to subscribe to @ViewChildren, everything works perfectly. The combination of both, however, outputs the error above.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer on stackoverflow. I flagged my answer as duplicate.

Comment: How do I make the duplicate flag "real"?